# Designing VS2012 project interaction: should I use an interface or a composite class across different projects?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, design-patterns

I have the following design problem. For example I have 3 visual studio projects. They are called "TheGame", "OpenGLDevice" and "DirectXDevice". "OpenGLDevice" and "DirectXDevice" are also the name of a class inside the projects. As you may have guessed, TheGame handles the logic of the application and use one of the other two projects to draw things on the screen. My question is about how should TheGame interact with the two projects. Here are what I could think of.

1. Create a "DeviceContainer" base class, and a "OpenGLDeviceContainer" and "DirectXDeviceContainer" derived private inner classes in TheGame. The derived classes each contains a private member field of type OpenGLDevice or DirectXDevice. DeviceContainer would basically serve as wrappers.
2. Create a "IGraphicsDevice" interface in a fourth project and have all three projects reference it. Make OpenGLDevice and DirectXDevice both implement that interface.

I like approach 1 because I wouldn't need to create a fourth project and both OpenGLDevice and DirectXDevice would have no dependencies.

First of all, which of these two would be the best approach and is there a third solution which would be even better.

Second, if I do choose to use the interface approach, is there a better way than to declare the interface in a fourth project?

Comment: If you use the second method, you don't need a new project, as the interface is just an abstract base class defined in a single header file. You can put this header file on your "TheGame" project, and just include it in the other projects.